# iptables - compound filter

Tags: linux, iptables

Is there a syntax to filter based on multiple interface criterion? E.g.

`iptables -A INPUT ! -i eth0 (and ! -i lo) -m limit --limit 5/s -j LOG --log-level 4`

Basically, I would like to include log entries for all interfaces except `eth0` and `lo`. More broadly, is there a way to create compound criterion with and/or like operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
#just a small example
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT (or REJECT)
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT (or REJECT)
iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/s -j LOG --log-level 4
```

When lo and eth0 packets are matched by ACCEPT or REJECT (depends on your setup), all other packets are limited, which applies for other interfaces.

Comment: +1 Iptables works on a first match wins so deal with everything you want to white list early on.

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not want to alter packet behavior but just log the relevant ones :-). In this case, I just want to log all packets that are not from eth0 and l0.